# How javaFx pass the drag event?

Tags: java, javafx, drag-and-drop, scenebuilder

I wrote some code to learn JavafX,
but very confuse by how Javafx pass event.
And sorry for the last version of code, here are the code I modified:

controller:

```
public class SecondaryController {
@FXML
Label soure;

@FXML
Label target;
@FXML
Button secondaryButton;

@FXML
private void switchToPrimary() throws IOException {
    App.setRoot("primary");
}

@FXML
private void drapDetected(MouseEvent event) {
    Dragboard dbss = soure.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.ANY); // source
    ClipboardContent cb = new ClipboardContent();
    cb.putString("here is the text");
    dbss.setContent(cb);
    System.out.println("Detected event");
    event.consume();
    System.out.println("Detected event, and event.consume() runed");
}
@

FXML
private void drapOver(DragEvent event) {
    System.out.println("drapOver runing");
    event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.ANY);

    event.consume();
}

@FXML
private void dropIn(DragEvent event) {
    System.out.println("dropIn");
    String str = event.getDragboard().getString();
    System.out.println(str);
    target.setText(str);
    event.setDropCompleted(true);
    event.consume();
}


@FXML
private void drapOver2(DragEvent event) {
    System.out.println("drapOver 2 runing");
    event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.ANY);         
    event.consume();
}

@FXML
private void dropIn2(DragEvent event) {
    System.out.println("dropIn 2");
    String str = event.getDragboard().getString();
    System.out.println(str);
    target.setText(str);
    event.setDropCompleted(true);
    event.consume();
}
```

}

And here is the fxml:

```
<VBox alignment="CENTER" onDragDropped="#dropIn2" onDragOver="#drapOver2" spacing="20.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="controller">
<children>
    <Label text="Secondary View" />
    <Button fx:id="secondaryButton" onAction="#switchToPrimary" text="Switch to Primary View" />
  <Label fx:id="soure" onDragDetected="#drapDetected" text="soure"  />
  <Label fx:id="target" onDragDropped="#dropIn" onMouseDragOver="#drapOver" text="target" />
</children>
```

- When I drop file out of the window:

And here is the console output when I drop some file in the window that after I run the code:

```
drapOver 2 runing
drapOver 2 runing
file:///home/galag/android-studio-ide-191.6010548-linux.tar.gz
```

- When I try to drag and drop Label soure:
  here is the console out put:

  Detected event
  Detected event
  Detected event, and event.consume() runed
  drapOver 2 runing

The question is : the Label target havent get the event, 
How can I let Label target get the event ?

Thank you!

PS. Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Please create a [mre] demonstrating the problem and then add it to your question via an [edit].

Comment: `<FontIcon fx:id="icon2" iconLiteral="fas-download" iconSize="80" layoutX="121.0" layoutY="177.0" wrappingWidth="84.0" />` I am not seeing any events have been assigned to this icon2 ?

Comment: well, you code .. but that's far from _minimal_ ;) Strip it down to smallest example that still has the issue, no need for tons of elements nor deep hierarchies - start with just a single icon in a not-nested gridpane. BTW (and again unrelated :), static scope is nearly always the wrong way to try achieve a goal, generally you _do not_ want each and every collaborator have access to internals.

Comment: Sorry, I modify the code to more minimal...